# How to store data when browser/mobile application when it get refreshed

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to React JS and I am building a website for web and mobile both in React JS, so I want to store Cart details once User has added products into Cart. So what kind of local storage I should use

I have explored for localStorage but I think it is only for browser not for mobile

Could anyone please suggest which localStorage I should use that is flexible in both browser and mobile

Comment: All of the major mobile browsers support local storage. [CanIUse support tables](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_localstorage), [MDN support tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#browser_compatibility)